# Is it possible to make a request from Lambda@Edge by origin response event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Is it possible to make a request from Lambda@Edge by origin response event?

```
User         L@E        Origin-1     Origin-2
 |            |            |            |
 |----GET---->|            |            |
 |            |----GET---->|            |
 |            |<---503-----|            |
 |            |            |            |
 |            |-----------------GET---->|
 |            |<----------------200-----|
 |<---200-----|            |            |
 |            |            |            |
```

If Lambda@Edge get response except 200 OK from Origin-1

Can Lambda@Edge make request to Origin-2?

Comment: [Origin Failover](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-cloudfront-announces-support-for-origin-failover) allows the behavior you describe, without L@E.  Will that do what you want?

Comment: Sorry late. Thank you for your information. I'll check this function.